# audio not working

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, linux

I reacently got a new computer and got blender on it, i was trying to make an animation, and when i tryed to put the sound in, it didn't work. the video didn't work at all, unless i was rendering it in AVI, so i used the ffmpeg video thing, and set the audio codec to mp3, and the normal codec to png. but when i rendered it and tryed to play the video, it had no sound. im shure the sound was on, and my speakers where on. i don't know what's wrong, im using linux mint. does anyone know why this woun't work? any help is appreciated.

Comment: nevermind, i needed to install codec things. new question: how do i delete a question?

Comment: what did you have to install? I had problem as well with render and sound, so please tell how you fixed your problem

Comment: I don't know, i can't remember, I think I juest renderd it, and when i clicked on the file, it told me to install somthing, so i did, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution comes from Richard Antalik, at developer.blender.org

Enable *Sequencer* in *Output Properties > Post Processing* panel.

In Blender 3.0 the *Output Properties* (tab) is where you define the size of your output, where to output your file to, encoding for video and audio, etc. You will also find in the same tab the *Post Processing* panel with compositing and sequencer check boxes. Put a check on the *Sequencer*.